# Where can I find the definition of mbuf_t

Tags: networking, kernel, bsd

I know that `mbuf_t` is defined as a pointer to `struct __mbuf`. I also know I'm supposed to treat it like a blind handle, but I feel I could understand the mbuf_*() functions if I could just look at the data structure they manipulate.

To be honest, I'm finding the [mbuf(9)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?format=html&query=mbuf(9)) man page hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

It's a core OS feature, the header should be `sys/sys/mbuf.h` or similar in your BSD's main source code. Since I presume mbuf is part of the kernel, the source is probably not particularly comprehensible from a userspace perspective.

Comment: I'm a kernel coder by trade (but new to BSD), so I should be able to figure it out.